# JPA Integer Discriminator Values

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

I'm trying to follow the [JPA tutorial](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance) and design a class hierarchy to represent the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE Entities (
  entity_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  entity_type INT CHECK (0 <= entity_type AND entity_type <= 2)
  entity_name VARCHAR(255)
);
```

This table is mapped into a class hierarchy:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance
@Table(schema="myschema", name="Entities")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="entity_type")
@SequenceGenerator(schema="myschema", name="entity_id_seq", sequenceName="entity_id_seq", allocationSize=100)
public abstract class LOTEntity {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="entity_id_seq")
  @Column(name="entity_id")
  protected long entityId;

  @Column(name="entity_name")
  protected String entityName = "";

  public LOTEntity() {}
  public LOTEntity(String name) { this.entityName = name; }
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("1")
class LOTClass extends LOTEntity {
  public LOTClass() {}
  public LOTClass(String name) { super(name); }
}
```

This does not work, however, since the `entity_type` is an `INT` rather than `String`:

> Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column
>   "entity_type" is of type integer but expression is of type character
>   varying

But if I change `@DiscriminatorValue("1")` to `@DiscriminatorValue(1)`, I get a compile error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to String

I need an integer here. Any quick suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On your `@DiscriminatorColumn` annotation, you need to specify the [`discriminatorType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/DiscriminatorType.html):

```
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="entity_type", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
```